# Can I use an Xbox 360 controller with the 4th Gen Apple TV (2015)?

Tags: appletv

Can I use my Xbox 360 controller with the 2015 (4th Gen) Apple TV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't connect an Xbox controller to an Apple TV at this point.